# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in single Chrome profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

Trying to log in as Admin to my Rails site running on Heroku, which has been successful for many, many days, but suddenly today is throwing "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" => ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error. I restarted the app and have confirmed the following:

1. Logging in as a non-admin user works fine (through the same sign-in page)
2. Logging in as the admin user through a different Chrome profile works fine.
3. Clearing the cookies for the app's domain in the problematic Chrome profile does not resolve the issue.
4. Clearing the cache using various methods (Cmd+Shift+R, Dev Tools + Empty Cache and Hard Reload, Disable cache while DevTools is open) does not resolve the issue.

Are there other things I can try?

Comment: you can check out this link https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2734

Comment: Nothing in that link seemed relevant to my case (in that making a code change doesn't seem like the way to go when I'm only seeing this within one Chrome profile), but I did upgrade Devise from 3.3.0 to 3.4.1 and I'm still having the same issue.